# How to check for custom Postgres exceptions raised via RAISE EXCEPTION in Golang?

Tags: postgresql, go, error-handling, pgx

**I'm using Postgres with Golang via [`pgx`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx)**

I've a trigger function something like the following:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (bar = 'baz') THEN
        -- something
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'oops error';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How do I check for `oops error` in Go code?

The way I'm doing it now is:

```golang
errOops := errors.New("ERROR: oops error (SQLSTATE P0001)")
err := myDBFunc()
if errors.Is(err, errOops) {

}
```

But I wonder if there's a better way other than relying on the hardcoded message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should have read the Wiki: [Error Handling in `pgx`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/wiki/Error-Handling)

So I can do:

```golang
var pgErr *pgconn.PgError
if errors.As(err, &pgErr) && pgErr.Code == "P0001" {

}
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that information in [appendix A of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html): it will be a `raise_exception`, and the SQLSTATE is `P0001`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. But I meant how to check it in Golang code. The code only returns an `error` type which, if I marshal to JSON and log, I get the code and message etc. But the actual variable, let's call it `err` only has an `Error` method (as expected).

Comment: Great, you found the missing information yourself.